# Use one sampling cypher query to filter the paths returned by another

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I have a large directed graph in a Neo4j database and wish to extract a representative sample subgraph, while respecting the structure of the graph.

Each node has either a `U`, `T`, `H`, `A` or `E` label. The graph is a forest of trees, with the root of each tree being a `U` node. The leaf nodes can be `T`, `H`, `A` or `E` nodes. Intermediate nodes are `T` nodes only. For the extract,

1. I wish to omit any `A` and `E` (leaf) nodes.
2. I want a 10% sample of the trees in the forest.

Note that an extract based on a simple sampling of the nodes would have a different structure to the overall graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The APOC procedures for [path expansion](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_expand_paths) should be very helpful.

For example, to get 10% of the subgraphs (as nodes):

```
MATCH (root:U)
WHERE rand() < .1
CALL apoc.path.subgraphNodes(root, {labelFilter:'-A|E'}) YIELD node
RETURN root, COLLECT(node) AS subgraph_nodes;
```

The `labelFilter` value specifies that `A` and `E` nodes should be blacklisted. You said that you did not want to return them as leaf nodes, and your description implies that they are only used as leaf nodes.

Comment: Thanks, I had not noticed this functionality in APOC. It looks better than mine! With a small change, it can return the relationships as well as the nodes: `CALL apoc.path.subgraphAll(root, {labelFilter:'-Asegment|Esegment'}) YIELD nodes, relationships
RETURN COLLECT(nodes), COLLECT(relationships);`

Comment: Regarding performance, they seem similar. Both run into scalability problems when the graph grows larger, even when the extract itself remains relatively small. They usually fail because of memory constraints (at least on my 8GB laptop). I might submit a separate question about that....

Answer (score 1):

I found [Sampling a Neo4j database](http://jexp.de/blog/2014/03/sampling-a-neo4j-database/) which helped me to write the first part of the cypher query:

```
MATCH (selectedU:U) WHERE rand() < 0.1 RETURN selectedU;
```

which returns approximately 10% of the `U` nodes, as required.

The following query returns the nodes and relationships I need (from the whole graph, because sampling has not been applied yet!):

```
MATCH p=(u:U)-->(n1)-[*]->(n2)
WHERE n1:T AND (n2:T OR n2:H)
WITH nodes(p) AS nodePairsInPath
UNWIND nodePairsInPath AS nodes
RETURN DISTINCT nodes AS g
UNION ALL
MATCH p=(u:U)-->(n1)-[*]->(n2)
WHERE n1:T AND (n2:T OR n2:H)
WITH relationships(p) AS relPairsInPath
UNWIND relPairsInPath AS rels
RETURN DISTINCT rels AS g;
```

I combined the two cypher queries, so that only the nodes and relationships in the paths starting with the selected `U` nodes would be returned:

```
MATCH (selectedU:U) WHERE rand() < 0.1
WITH selectedU
MATCH p=(selectedU)-->(n1)-[*]->(n2)
WHERE n1:T AND (n2:T OR n2:H)
WITH nodes(p) AS nodePairsInPath
UNWIND nodePairsInPath AS nodes
RETURN DISTINCT nodes AS g
UNION ALL
MATCH p=(selectedU)-->(n1)-[*]->(n2)
WHERE n1:T AND (n2:T OR n2:H)
WITH relationships(p) AS relPairsInPath
UNWIND relPairsInPath AS rels
RETURN DISTINCT rels AS g;
```

There is still a small problem in that, if the sampling size is too small (so that no `selectedU` is found), the combined query returns relationships between the `U`, `T` and `H` nodes. It would be better for the query to return no records (either nodes or relationships) in such edge cases.

I think that this might be a common use case, where a random subgraph is required, but the subgraph needs to follow the structure of the overall graph.
As a novice cypher user, this proved quite challenging to me, so I am posting it here in the hope that it might benefit others with similar requirements.

Writing this cypher query taught me a lot about the language, although I expect cypher experts could do better...